# Passing parameters into Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I would like to pass 2 ports as a parameter into Windows Service during OnStart. I have seen a few examples around and came across this guide [C# Windows Service Startup Arguments](http://derpturkey.com/c-windows-service-startup-arguments/). This code is working when I pass a parameter but when I try to pass two parameters, I got an error `Start Service fail 1053`. The code is as below.

```
namespace MyService  
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            uint port = uint.Parse(args[1]);
            uint port2 = uint.Parse(args[2]);

            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;        
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new MyService(port,port2);
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
    }
}
```

The code below is my service code.

```
namespace MyService  
{
    public partial class MyService : ServiceBase
    {
        public uint Port { get; set; }
        public uint Port2 { get; set; }

        public MyService(uint port, uint port2)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Port = port;
            Port2 = port2;
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            if(args.Length > 0) {
                Port = uint.Parse(args[1]);
                Port2 = uint.Parse(args[2]);
            }

            // DO STUFF
        }
    }
}
```

I installed it using the following command.

```
sc create WindowsService1 binPath= "C:\Users\user\Desktop\abc\Projects\WindowsService1\bin\x86\Debug\WindowsService1.exe --port 3000 --port 2000"
```

and Start using the following command

```
sc start WindowsService1 --port 3000 --port 2000
```

Comment: I would imagine that you get an exception when you call `uint.Parse("--port")`

Comment: I don't think there is a problem there because when I use only 1 port, I still call `--port 3000` and now I'm trying to add `--port 2000` behind.

Comment: That's because `args[1]` is the second argument, i.e., `3000`, but `args[2]` is the third argument, i.e., it is `--port`.

Comment: Harry has identified the problem. Your parsing code is wrong, because you're not accounting for removing the `--port` switch. If you don't believe us, add some debugging code to output the args to a file and see what you're actually receiving and trying to parse.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I get what you mean now. Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite I get what Harry meant now. Thanks.